# No sound when connect a headphone

Tags: drivers, sound, 17.04, headphones

I have an LG All-in-one and I use the Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. I'm having a problem with the sound.
When I plug in the headphone there is no sound, neither the handphone nor the speaker, it is necessary that I restart to return the sound. This problem also happens if I turn off the screen.
Does anyone know what I should do to solve this problem?
The machine specs:

```
System: Host: wolney-23V545-G-BK55P1 Kernel: 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
Desktop: Gnome 3.24.2 (Gtk 3.22.11-0ubuntu3) Distro: Ubuntu 17.04
Machine: Device: laptop System: LG product: 23V545-G.BK55P1 v: 0.1
Mobo: LG model: White Tip Mountain v: FAB3
UEFI: Phoenix v: VIC2SF01 date: 04/25/2014
CPU: Dual core Intel Core i5-4200M (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9976
clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2499 MHz 2: 2500 MHz 3: 2523 MHz
4: 2499 MHz
Graphics: Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
bus-ID: 00:02.0
Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 driver: N/A
Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio: Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-32-generic
Network: Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Card-2: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 04:00.0
IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives: HDD Total Size: 1032.2GB (29.8% used)
ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB
ID-2: /dev/sdb model: SATA_SSD size: 32.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 46G used: 5.5G (13%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
ID-2: /home size: 424G used: 276G (69%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
ID-3: swap-1 size: 6.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info: Processes: 219 Uptime: 13 min Memory: 1419.3/7889.1MB
Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.3.0
Client: Shell (bash 4.4.71) inxi: 2.3.8
```

Comment: install pavucontrol and see which ports is sound going by, or if there is some misleading at sound profiles at configuration tab.

Comment: Shows only one port: Digital Output (S / PDIF)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer) check for mute ('M' key).
Try sudo alsa force-reload instead of reboot.